$G$ is finite iff $G/N$ and $N$ are finite
Let $G$ be a group and let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Prove or disprove:
a) $G$ is finite iff $G/N$ and $N$ are finite.
b) if $[G:N]=n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then for all $g\in G$ holds that $g^n\in N$.
c) if $N$ and $G/N$ are Abelian, then so is $G$.
I was able to disprove c), since we can take $G:=D_8$ and $N:=\langle r\rangle$, so then $N$ is cyclic and hence Abelian and also $G/N$ is a group of prime order $2$ is therefore cyclic and so Abelian, but $G$ is obviously not Abelian.
I was also able to prove b): If $[G:N]=n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $|G/N|=n$. But then for all $g\in G$ it holds $(gN)^n=N$ and also $(gN)^n=g^nN$, so consequently $g^n\in N$.
I am unable to prove or disprove a). I was looking for a counterexample, but couldn't find one. Actually, if $G$ is finite, Lagrange tells us that $|G|=|G/N||N|$, so $G/N$ and $N$ must also be finite. But Lagrange does not provide us other implication. So, is this statement true in general or not?
Added: I thought about starting like this: If $G/N$ is finite, then $a_1N,...,a_nN$ are all the left cosets in $G$. What can I do now?

Note, a simpler (well, at least smaller) example for $c)$ is just $S_3$, smallest non-abelian group, with $N$ the normal subgroup of order $3$.

For $a)$ note that any element of $G$ can be written as a pair $a\cdot b$ where $\phi(g)=a$ and $b\in N$ (here $\phi:  G\to G/N$ denotes the quotient map.

You have too simple a statement of Lagrange's Theorem, The usual proof actually proves this: for any group $G$ and normal subgroup $N$ the set $G$ is a disjoint union of the cosets of $N$ in $G$; and also, there is a bijection between any coset $Nx$ of $N$ and $N$ itself.

I don't understand your last statement @lulu. I thought about starting like this: If $G/N$ is finite, then $a_1N,...,a_nN$ are all the left cosets in $G$. What can I do now?

So, every element in $G$ is in (exactly) one of those cosets.  Thus, if $g\in G$, we have $g\in a_iN$ for some $a_i$ which means that $\phi(g)=a_i$ and $g=a_i\cdot n_g$ for some $n_g\in N$.

But do we really need canonical epimorphism?

What do you mean?

I mean do we really need to work with $\phi$?

The set $G$ is the union of all sets of the form $gN$, and there are only finitely many of them. Besides, each $gN$ has as many elements as $N$, which is finite. Therefore, $G$ is finite.
